# Find the last values of a variable in Altair

Tags: python, visualization, altair, vega-lite

I'm trying to create a bar chart in Altair showing the final values of a graph that shows accumulated sums of data per class.

Starting with creating a graphs that shows the accumulating sum:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"time":[1,2,3,1,2,3], "value": [1,5,2,2,3,7], "class": ["A","A","A","B","B","B"]})

base = alt.Chart(df).transform_window(
    cumulative = "sum(value)",
    groupby = ["class"],
    frame = [None, 0],
)

base.mark_line().encode(
    x = "time:Q",
    y = "cumulative:Q",
    # detail = "class",
    color = "class"
)
```

[image]

Now I want to create a bar graph, that shows "A" and "B" on the x-axis and the final value of the lines above (i.e. 8 for "A" and 12 for "B") on the y-axis.

I thought I should do that like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
base2 = base.transform_window(
    final = "last_value(cumulative)",
    groupby = ["class"],
    sort = [alt.SortField(field = "time")],
    frame = [None, None],
)

base2.mark_bar().encode(
    x = "class",
    y = "final:Q",
)
```

It gives me a value of 24 for "A" and 36 for "B". Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular use case, rather than using a `window` transform, it seems like you could use a simple `aggregate` ([link](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/aggregate.html)) to compute the final values for the bar chart based on the original dataframe (df):

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    y='final:Q',
    x='class:O'
).transform_aggregate(
    final='sum(value)',
    groupby=["class"]
)
```

In some ways, this side-steps the question you asked (computing the last value), but given the use case of a cumulative aggregate, this more straightforward solution seems to address the key problem posed here.

Looking at the code and partial results you shared, I wonder if your solution is actually close to working. It looks like the two values you are getting are each 3x the value you want (e.g., 8*3=24, 12*3=36). Given that you have three data points for each class, I think what is happening is that you are computing the `last_value` from your cumulative result, but when you create the bars it is summing them because you still have six data points in your dataframe, with each data point having the `last_value` column set as expected. To get only one data point with the last value, an option might be to then produce an aggregate using `min` or `max` on the `last_value`, grouped by "class" (the one you use does not really matter, given that each data point has the same value for the particular class.